# Should my custom popup window be a singleton?

Tags: c#, winforms, singleton

I have popup custom windows in my DLL used by 3-4 other DLLs.  These windows popup in a modal manner.

Should my custom window be a singleton?

Should it be called as follows:

```
 NeXusCustomWindowDlg.Instance.CustomWndDlg.Show("Recipe properties", ctl, 600, 600);
 ...
 NeXusCustomWindowDlg.Instance.Close()
```

Relevant code:

```
    public void Show(string title, object content, double width, double height)
    {
        Window newWindow = new Window
        {
            BorderBrush = Brushes.Blue,
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(3),
            Title = title,
            Content = content,
            WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.ToolWindow,
            WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen,
            ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize,
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch
        };

        //WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None,
        OpenedWindow = newWindow;
        newWindow.ShowDialog();
        newWindow.Content = null;

    }

    public void Close()
    {
        if (OpenedWindow != null)
        {
            OpenedWindow.Close();
        }

    }

    private Window OpenedWindow
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_syncObj)
            {
                return _openedWindow;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_syncObj)
            {
                _openedWindow = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be disposed after closing?

Comment: i think, method close dispose the window

Comment: Why do you think making it a Singleton is a good idea? I could agree with making the `Show` method static (if it returns the window), but a Singleton seems not reasonable.

Comment: Nico, thanks for answer. Why is a bad idea? thanks